# Entropy of Independent/Dependent Messages

Tags: entropy, information-theory

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two messages each having $16$ possible values. What is the joint entropy $H_{AB}%$if (a) $A$ and $B$ are independent and (b) $B$ is known to be an exact copy of $A$?

So if $A$ and $B$ are independent then the joint entropy is  $$H_{AB} = \log 16 + \log 16 = \log(256) \approx 5.54$$

If $B$ is an exact copy of $A$ then the joint entropy is $$H_{AB} = \log 16 \approx 2.77 $$

Is this correct?

Comment: Is this a homework? If yes, please add `[self-study]` tag.

Comment: Do please add the tag as @Tim said. Your reasoning is correct iff the messages are equally likely.